# Must be an array type but resolved to string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am getting the "Must be an array type but it resolved to string" error in my code. It also says that i (in the code below) cannot be resolved to a variable which I don't get.

```
    public class DNAcgcount{

        public double ratio(String dna){
        int count=0;
        for (int i=0;i<dna.length();i++);
            if (dna[i]== "c"){
            count+= 1;
            if (dna[i]=="g"){
            count+=1;
        double answer = count/dna.length();
        return answer;

    }

    }


}
```

}

Could you guys please help me figure out where the problem lies? I'm new to coding in Java so I am not entirely comfortable with the format yet.

Thanks a lot,
Junaid

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your for statement, for a starter.

Comment: You should align subordinate clauses, and properly embed them in `{ ... }` so that one can see what you even mean.

Comment: @Ingo Actually, OP should read some introductory tutorials, to be honest :) This is the worst case of programming by trial-and-error I have seen in quite some time.

Comment: @Vash Please don't alter the question by fixing the errors in the code!

Comment: @tobias_k, The alter was made to focus on the error. As the { issues ware not related to it. I have done this as the question will stay on SO and can be important for other user in future.

Comment: @Vash OP points out that `i` can not be resolved, so that _was_ another error.

Comment: @tobias_k, You have right. I read that as the i form the array can not be resolved not as compile error.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot access a String's character using subscript (`dna[i]`). Use charAt instead:

```
dna.charAt(i) == 'c'
```

Also, `"c"` is a `String`, `'c'` is a `char`.

One more thing - integer division ( e.g. `int_a / int_b` ) results in an int, and so you lose accuracy, instead - cast one of the `int`s to `double`:

```
double answer = count/(double)dna.length();
```

Comment: So I must use 'c' instead of "c"? Also, it still says that i cannot be resolved to a variable? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2904796 - yes. And some of your errors are not displayed in the question, as someone already edited it. Look at the edits he performed, modify your code, and try again.

Comment: declaring count as
double count = 0;
would also do the job.

Comment: @pshemek - sure, I prefer to do it this way, but I guess it's a matter of taste..

Answer (score 2):

Use `{}` to define the scope of the loop. Also, as others already pointed out, use `charAt` instead of `[]` and use `'` for characters, and use floating point division for the `ratio`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dna.length(); i++) {
    if (dna.charAt(i) == 'c') {
        count += 1;
    }
    if (dna.charAt(i) == 'g') {
        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Or a bit shorter, use `||` to *or* the two clauses together

```
if (dna.charAt(i) == 'c' || dna.charAt(i) == 'g') {
    count += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are currently a bit weak at brackets , this is what i understood from your code and corrected it;

```
public class DNAcgcount{

    public double ratio(String dna){
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
        if (dna.charAt(i)== 'c')
        count+= 1;
        if (dna.charAt(i)=='g')
        count+=1;
    }
        double answer = count/(double)dna.length();
        return answer;
    }
}
```

After if we have to close the brackets when what you want in if is finished . I think you wanted `count` to be the number of time `c` or `g` is present in the `dna`.
You also did some other mistakes like you have to use `'c'` and `'g'` instead of `"c"` and `"g"` if you are using `.charAt(i)` because it will be treated like a character and then only you can compare . 
You may view this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

and you may also have a look at works you can do with string like charAt.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that you have a few problems with the main syntax of basic java functions like `loops` or `if-else` statement. Click [here](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/tutorials/java/java1.php) for a good tutorial on these.

You must correct your `for-loop` and your `if-statement`:

```
for(int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
    if(...){
       ...;
    }
    if(...){
       ...;
    }
}
```

Now you wont get the `Cant be resolved to a variable... exception`.

Second thing is the usage of your string. You have to use it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<dna.length();i++){
    if(dna.charAt(i) == 'c'){
       count += 1;
    }
    if(dna.charAt(i) == 'g'){
       count += 1;
    }
}
```

Now all your exceptions should be eleminated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with syntax `dna[i]`, `dna` is a string and you access it as it would be an array by `[]`. Use `dna.charAt(i);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You using `String` incorrectly. Instead of accessing via `[]` use `dna.charAt(i)`.

Altough logically a string is an array of characters in Java a `String` type is a class (which means it has attributes and methods) and not a typical array.

And if you want to compare a single character to another enclose it with '' instead of "":

```
if (dna.charAt(i) == 'c')
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors:

count should be double or should be casted do  double answer = (double)count / dna.length();

and  as mentioned above you should replace dna[i] with dna.charAt(i)